# Matching jumbled strings and returning corresponding column value in R

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

Below is a data frame with two columns of character data type in R. My requirement is that suppose if I have a jumbled string "FB,AI,IT,GE", I want to test if this jumbled string exists in the "a2 column", then return the corresponding "a1 column" value. Clearly, the first "a2 column" value is what matches with the jumbled string above, I need the corresponding "a1" value to be returned. I would appreciate is using "if-else" is avoided.

```
a1 = c("B1","B2","B3","B4","B5")
a2 = c("IT,GE,FB,AI","GE,AI","FB,IT,AI","GE,IT,FB","AI")
a12 = data.frame(a1,a2)
a12$a1 = as.character(a12$a1)
a12$a2 = as.character(a12$a2)
```

Comment: "FB,AI,IT,GE" should be an exact match? No values extra or less?

Comment: @RonakShah, Thank you so much for replying, absolutely exact, nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: Something like : `a12$a1[sapply(strsplit(a12$a2, ","), function(x) all(strsplit(val, ",")[[1]] %in% x))]`. Don't think this is an efficient method though.

Comment: @RonakShah, it works, but as I said, nothing less, nothing more, I tried using other strings like "AI", it is returning multiple "a1" values, need a little tweak here, kindly check.

Comment: @RonakShah, Also, I would greatly appreciate, if this can be achieved without using function, as it has the possibility of slowing down the process on large data, I suppose.

Comment: @AdamShaw I'd recommend asking this question on the https://community.rstudio.com/ to get a good response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#string to be matched
match_str <- "FB,AI,IT,GE"

idx <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(a12$a2),","), 
              function(x) setequal(unlist(strsplit(as.character(match_str),",")), unlist(x)))
a12$a1[idx]
```

Output is:

```
[1] "B1"
```

```
#sample data
> dput(a12)
structure(list(a1 = c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"), a2 = c("IT,GE,FB,AI", 
"GE,AI", "FB,IT,AI", "GE,IT,FB", "AI")), .Names = c("a1", "a2"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: very nice, still, I would be very thankful if this can be achieved without using a function, like say if my string is "IT,GE,FB,AI", a12$a1[a12$a2 == "IT,GE,FB,AI"], this will solve the problem. I know this is the exact string, but if something like this can be done for jumbled too, thanks and kindly suggest.

Comment: Above solution is the vectorized one and it's not going to slow your processing. I don't think you can achieve it without splitting your string either on `''` or `','`.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot for your help, still if you can find a fix, please let me know.